# Ignore file import if there is no such in webpack (local config)

Tags: typescript, webpack, config

I want to make possible to add local config file that will not be under git.
Like this:

```
import { config as configLocal } from './local';
import { config as configDefault } from './default';

export var config = configLocal ? Object.assing(configDefault, configLocal) : configDefault;
```

Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

Made it simpler, I created the local config file by hand with this [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pre-build-webpack). But it is not answer on the question's title.

Comment: Can you elaborate bit more. what you meant by local config and git config?

Comment: I don't think you can have import statements ignored. The alternative would be to have webpack load another file that exports an empty object and do a runtime check.

Comment: @toskv does webpack have a callback to define what file it should load? If so I can load another file with emty object.

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran there are told nothing about git config. I don't want to put local configs in git repository.